# Thumbnails versions of user profile photo not created SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, userprofiles

User updated the image on mysite. For a some user thumbnails versions _LThumb.jpg, _MThumb.jpg, _SThumb.jpg are not created under User Profile/Profile Pictures library on mysite.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the following command to update the profile photo store and thumbnail versions.

Powershell command:

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation https://mysites -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos:$true
```

There is a possibility of this not working for all the users in the first iteration . Run it again and you will see that your problem is solved.

Don't forget to run Crawl after this if you want to see the updated photos reflected in your sites.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It helped.

Comment: Any idea why this issue occurred in first place?

Comment: Cannot really say but one thing is for sure that at some point of time your synchronization didn't work properly. This is the only explanation that we can think of . You can always refer to the logs though for the issue